# How to make different picture using carousel slider in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

```
        CarouselSlider(
          items: [0, 1, 2, 3].map((e) {
            return Image.asset('assets/images/onboarding6.png');
          }).toList(),
```

this is my code

how to make different pictures using the carousel slider?

pic below is my UI Program

[image: [UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODAjy.png)]

Answer (score 0):

```
    CarouselSlider(
              items: [
                      'assets/images/onboarding1.png', 
                      'assets/images/onboarding2.png', 
                      'assets/images/onboarding3.png', 
                      'assets/images/onboarding4.png',
                     ].map((e) {
                return Image.asset(e);
              }).toList(),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> _images=['assets/images/one.png','assets/images/two.png','assets/images/three.png','assets/images/four.png',];

CarouselSlider(items:_images.map((e)=>return Image.asset(e)).toList(),
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?